# Different cumulative incidence estimates obtained with `prodlim` and `survfit` for a simple competing risks dataset

Tags: r, survival

I have a question regarding the cumulative incidence curves obtained using `prodlim`, which seems to differ quite a lot compared to the ones that I can obtain from the `survfit` function in the `survival` package.  In a relatively basic competing risks setup, I would expect the two implementations to give more similar results. As far as I understand, they are both implementing the Aalen-Johansen estimator. My question is basically

- Am I wrong to expect that the two implementations should be identical?
- Do you know if the two implementations differ in a methodological perspective?

As a reprex, we can use some example data from “Kleinbaum, David G., and Mitchel Klein.
Survival analysis: a self-learning text. Vol. 3. New York: Springer, 2012.”
which looks like this:

```r
data <- list(
  cens = c(3.2, 7.6, 10, 11, 15, 24.4),
  cause_1 = c(0.7, 3, 4.9, 6, 6, 6.9, 10, 10.8, 17.1, 20.3),
  cause_2 = c(1.5, 2.8, 3.8, 4.7, 7, 10, 10, 11.2)
)
```

For reference, I'm using the following libraries

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(prodlim)
```

First I wrangle the data into a tabular format that can be used by `prodlim` and `survfit`

```r
df <- data |> 
  enframe("status", "time") |> 
  unnest(time) |> 
  mutate(
    status = factor(status, levels = c("cens", "cause_1", "cause_2"))
  )
```

And then, fitting and tidying the results from survfit

```r
sfit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df)
pstate <- summary(sfit)$pstate
colnames(pstate) <- c("cens", "cause_1", "cause_2")
sfit_tidy <- as_tibble(pstate) |> 
  add_column(time = summary(sfit)$time) |> 
  pivot_longer(-time, names_to = "cause", values_to = "cuminc")
```

... and similarly for prodlim

```r
pfit <- prodlim(Hist(time, status) ~ 1, data = df)
pfit_tidy <- map_dfr(summary(pfit)$table, as_tibble, .id = "cause") |> 
  select(cause, time, cuminc)
```

If we compare the cumulative incidence curves they differ quite alot. As far
as I understand, the two methods both use the Aalen-Johansen estimator and
I have a hard time understanding why the shouldn’t be identical.

```r
bind_rows(sfit = sfit_tidy, pfit = pfit_tidy, .id = "method") |> 
  filter(cause != "cens") |> 
  ggplot(aes(time, cuminc, color = method)) +
  geom_step() +
  facet_wrap(~cause)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Please let me know if this is off-topic for Cross-Validated and instead should be posted to stackoverflow. My impression was that more people here would be familiar with the packages in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could easily have been a CrossValidated question, but it turns out to be more a StackOverflow one.

If you look at `pfit`

```
> pfit

Call: prodlim(formula = Hist(time, status) ~ 1, data = df)


No covariates

Uncensored response of a competing.risks model

No.Observations: 24 

Pattern:
         
Cause     event
  cens        6
  cause_1    10
  cause_2     8
  unknown     0
```

So the problem is with the censoring (what I noticed is that the curves start to separate after the first censoring).  In `survfit()` the first level of a factor is automatically taken as censoring, but in `Hist()` there's a `cens.code` argument to set the censoring level.   If you do

```
pfit <- prodlim(Hist(time, status,cens.code="cens") ~ 1, data = df)
```

you get
[image]

Comment: Ah! That explains it - good catch.